# Show Error "The upload path does not appear to be valid"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making form upload file image, but I have a problem when upload.

My controller

```
public function post(){ 
        $config['file_name'] = 'pict_'.date('Y_m_d_H_i_s');
        $config['upload_path'] = './monyet';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG';
        $config['max_size'] = '8000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1366';
        $config['max_height']  = '1024';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] == "") {                                 
            $datanya = array(   'titlenews'     => $this->input->post('titlenews'),
                                'userid'        => $this->input->post('userid'),
                                'postdate'      => $this->input->post('postdate'),
                                'contentnews'   => $this->input->post('contentnews')
                            );
            $this->m_news->post($datanya);
            redirect('admin/c_news/post');
        }else{
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                echo 'Error Bos';
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }else{
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $datanya = array( 
                                    'titlenews'     => $this->input->post('titlenews'),
                                    'userid'        => $this->input->post('userid'),
                                    'postdate'      => $this->input->post('postdate'),
                                    'contentnews'   => $this->input->post('contentnews'),
                                    'pictnews'      => $data['file_name']
                                );
                $this->m_news->post($datanya);
                redirect('admin/c_news');
            }
        }
    }
```

My view

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('admin/c_news/post') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="postdate" value="<?php echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+60*60*7) ?>" />

                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h4 class="header green clearfix">
                        Judul Berita
                    </h4>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titlenews" placeholder="Content News" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h4 class="header green clearfix">
                        Gambar Berita
                    </h4>
                    <input type="file" name="userfile" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h4 class="header green clearfix">
                        Isi Berita
                    </h4>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="contentnews"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="hr hr-double dotted"></div>

                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-white btn-round">
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-floppy-o bigger-125"></i>
                            Simpan
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

When I submitted the file can't upload and shown error "The upload path does not appear to be valid". What's problem on my code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set the upload path for the Codeigniter upload library on a local machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563484/how-do-you-set-the-upload-path-for-the-codeigniter-upload-library-on-a-local-mac)

Comment: In order for us to know if the path is correct, we need to know your file structure. Please add your file structure. You can do this by going to this site: **http://www.filestructuregenerator.com**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could try

Double check monyet folder in main directory

`$config['upload_path'] = './monyet/';` 
**adding extra forward slash '/'**

`$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'monyet/';`